# Ansible - unarchive module not working with busy box tools

Tags: ansible, busybox

I am trying to unzip a file on an embedded system that has busy box.

```
- name: Unarchive media files
  unarchive:
    src: /home/root/archive.zip
    dest: /home/root/
    remote_src: yes
```

I am getting the following error:

```
fatal: [10.0.6.41]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to find handler for \"/home/root/archive.zip\". Make sure the required command to extract the file is installed.\nCommand \"/bin/tar\" detected as tar type None. GNU tar required.\nCommand \"unzip -Z\" could not handle archive: /usr/bin/unzip: invalid option -- 'Z'\nBusyBox v1.31.1 () multi-call binary.\n\nUsage: unzip [-lnojpq] FILE[.zip] [FILE]... [-x FILE...] [-d DIR]\n\nUnable to find required 'zipinfo' binary in the path."}
```

Seems like it requires GNU tar? If I run `unzip archive.zip` directly on the command line on the remote source, it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last portion of your log says everything:

```
Unable to find required 'zipinfo' binary in the path
```

Ansible tries to run `unzip -Z` which is the same as `zipinfo`:

```
Command \"unzip -Z\" could not handle archive: /usr/bin/unzip: invalid option -- 'Z'
```

From `unarchive` module [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/unarchive_module.html):

> Requires `zipinfo` and `gtar`/`unzip` command on target host.

It's not the Ansible way, but if you're on an embedded system and with `busybox` chances are that you will not be able to install `zipinfo` or any other package. So you can always run `unzip` directly using [`command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html) or [`shell`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html) module:

```yaml
- name: Unarchive media files
  command:
    cmd: unzip archive.zip
    creates: archive
    chdir: /home/root/
```

Comment: Ok so I guess busybox `unzip` command doesn't have `Z` option.

Comment: Yes. But you still have options - I've updated my answer and added an example.

Comment: Why is “creates” needed ?  Unzipping using shell command creates a directory of the same name anyways.

Comment: [creates](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#parameter-creates) just provides an ability to assure idempotency (e.g. not run a task if a certain file is already in place or vice versa). It helps to save the execution time and provide a correct play recap. Typically Ansible modules are idempotent, but this quality gets lost when shell commands are used instead. So usage of `creates`/`removes` is a recommendation, not a requirement. And, of course, you don't need it if the archive should be copied and unpacked on every run.